# (SWIFT2.1) what Expected Expression after operator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, expression

I'm working on app that requires a table view in it, and i mean by that passing data between table views using structs and arrays. I have an issue [image]

As you see in the picture above after "prepare for segue" there is an issue and i spend days trying to solve but i cant find any solution.

So the question is what expression does this operator expect ?

Comment: Man, that error aint true... You should get rid of the "space" between "indexPathForSelectedRow()" and "!"

Comment: use operator ! not |

Comment: Guys, I'm 99% certain the `|` isn't the "or" character but the text cursor... :)

Answer (score 0):

`|` isn't what you're looking for.
Write :

`let destViewController = seque.destinationViewController as! ModelsTableViewController 
//I made some improvements like let and naming convention`

And you should use optionals to improve your code security :

```
if let destViewController = seque.destinationViewController as? ModelsTableViewController {
   //Now you're sure destViewController is allocated
   //Do your stuff here
}
```

You also should use good naming conventions for naming. Like (it's a bonus) :

```
STHModelsTableViewController
```

Comment: if the segue with destination `ModelsTableViewController` is wired up in Interface Builder it's absolutely safe and any optional binding is not necessary at all.

Comment: You're right but personally I prefer to add these controls points. Do you know if there's some conventions guidelines provided for those cases ?

Comment: I'm afraid, no, it's up to the developer to take care of these cases at design time to get the best performance at runtime.

Comment: @Pierre thank you. '|' is a text cursor, and i tried doing it your way but it still gives me an error.

Comment: I didn't see your ! on the first line. What's its purpose ? Remove it

Answer (score 0):

remove the space before ! in second line

```
let i: Int? = 1
let j = i !
// Excepted expression after operator
```

...

```
let i: Int? = 1
let j = i!  // works!
```